# Find all solutions to the equation $z^5 = 2 -2i$ and express answers in polar form

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

So far I have used De Moivres theorem to get $R^5=\sqrt{8}$ and $5\arg(z)=-\frac{1}{4}\pi$.
$z=(\sqrt{8})(\cos(-\frac{1}{4}\pi)+i\mkern1mu\sin(-\frac{1}{4}\pi))^\frac{1}{5}$.

Then by bringing the power down:
$z=(\sqrt{8})^\frac{1}{5}(\cos(-\frac{1}{20}\pi)+i\sin(-1/20\pi))$.
So now I'm confused about solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have:

$z^5 = \sqrt 8(\cos -\frac {\pi}{4} + i\sin-\frac {\pi}{4})\\
z = 8^\frac {1}{10}(\cos -\frac {\pi}{4} + i\sin-\frac {\pi}{4})^\frac 15\\
z = 8^\frac {1}{10}(\cos -\frac {\pi}{20} + i\sin-\frac {\pi}{20})$

And this is all good to find one value of $z.$  But there are others.  We can rewrite the first line as:

$z^5 = 8^\frac 12(\cos (-\frac {\pi}{4}+2n\pi) + i\sin(-\frac {\pi}{4}+2n\pi)\\
z = 8^\frac 1{10}(\cos (-\frac {\pi}{20}+\frac {2n\pi}{5}) + i\sin(-\frac {\pi}{20}+\frac {2n\pi}{5})$

and set $n = 1,2,3,4$ for the other roots.

Comment: Ah this makes more sense thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you were taught, but to find the solutions to $z$ you don't actually need to express it in polar form (e.g. $z=r$cis$(\theta)$). You do, however, need to express $2-2i\mkern1mu$ in polar form. So, as you've done, $2-2i\mkern1mu = \sqrt{8}$cis$\frac{7}{4}\pi$.

Then, using De Moivre's formula, we get that $z=\sqrt{8}^\frac{1}{5}$cis$(\frac{7}{20}\pi+\frac{2}{5}\pi k), k\in\mathbb{Z}$

From here, the next five solutions (e.g. for the next $k$ values) will be your solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer :

$z^5 =2(1-i)$

We put $z=Re^{i\theta} $

$R^5 e^{i5\theta} =2( e^{-\frac {i\pi}{2}} (i+1))=2\sqrt{2} (e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}(\frac{\sqrt {2}}{2} +\frac{i\sqrt {2}}{2})) =2\sqrt{2} (e^{-\frac{i\pi}{2}}(e^{i\frac{\pi}{4}})=2\sqrt{2} e^{-i\frac{\pi}4}$

$\Rightarrow $ $R=\sqrt[5]{2\sqrt{2}} $ and $5\theta=\frac{-\pi}{4}+2k\pi$

$\Rightarrow $$ R=\sqrt[5]{2\sqrt{2}}$ and$ \theta=\frac{-\pi}{20}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}$

$\Rightarrow $ $ z= \sqrt[5]{2\sqrt{2}}e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{20}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}) }=\sqrt[5]{\sqrt{8}}e^{i(-\frac{\pi}{20}+\frac{2k\pi}{5}) }$

$k ={0,1,2,3,4} $